# Keras, Conv1D: printing / plotting information of kernel_size on summary() or using plot_model()

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network

In keras, I have a model involving keras.layers.Conv1D, and try to plot it. E.g., here is a simple example:

```python
from keras.models import Sequential,Model
from keras.layers import Conv1D
from keras.utils import plot_model
from IPython.display import Image, display


seq_length = None
M=6
kernel_size = 3
filters=1

model = Sequential()
model.add(
    Conv1D(
        filters = filters, 
        kernel_size = kernel_size, 
        input_shape=(seq_length, M),#When using this layer as the first layer in a model, provide an input_shape argument 
    )        
)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
print 'Trainable params = ({}[filters])*((6[input_shape[1]])x({}[kernel_size]])+(1[bias])) = {}'.format(filters,kernel_size,M*kernel_size+1)
plot_model(model, to_file='model.png',show_shapes=True)
display(model.summary())
display(Image(filename='model.png'))
```

This gives the summary and the plot of the model fine:
[image]
Furthermore, the total params are correctly identified as:

```python
(1[filters])*((6[input_shape[1]])x(3[kernel_size]])+(1[bias])) = 19
```

However, the information about the kernel_size being 3 is nowhere to my knowledge displayed...

Questions:

1. The input is displayed as: (None, None, 6)... Why is that not e.g.  (None, 3, 6)?...  (is this some bug, or am I missing something?)
2. Is there a way to display the kernel_size either on the summary or the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For question 1:**

- The input shape is: `(batchSize, sequenceLength, features)`
- While the output shape is: `(batchSize, newSequenceLength, layerFilters)`

The shapes shown do not contain information about the size of the kernel. The filters are applied "along the sequence". The same filter is calculated step by step througout the sequence. It's the same process, no matter the size of the sequence.

The only number the kernel size may change is the `newSequenceLength`, if you're using `padding='valid'` (the default value). When using `padding='valid'`, you will lose the borders of the sequence:

```
newSequenceLength = sequenceLength - (kernel_size - 1)
```

If a sequence has length 3, the kernel will be calculated once, using these 3 steps. If a sequence has length 4, the kernel will be calculated twice. Once for the first 3 steps, once for the last 3. If the length is 5, the kernel will be applied 3 times, once for each group of 3 steps. And so on...

If you're using `padding='same'`, though, the output length will be the same as the input length (keras will pad the input with enough steps, so the output after losing the borders is the same length as the input)

**Why `None`**?

The `None` dimension in keras is used in cases where the model allows that dimension to have any size. For this model, you can use any batch size, and any sequence length.

**For question 2:**

Not that I'm aware of. But you can always check:

```
for layer in model.layers:
    if hasattr(layer,'kernel_size'):
        print(layer.kernel_size)
```

Comment: Thanx. I will accept this answer since it is answering my question and is very informative for anyone starting to look in Conv1D. I am still not satisfied why this is the case that the kernel_size is not in any way plotted and worry my understanding is wrong... Let me make an example: I have an conv1D layer (as in example), followed by a Dense Layer, (with say 3 Neurons) If kernel_size is 1 then I move from 7 to 3 Neurons. If it is 3 from 19 to 3... So as I decide the Model, kernel_size should be very relevant information. Yet when I print it, its not even displayed... This is unexpected...

Comment: Not "neurons", but "parameters/weights". Yes, the bigger the kernel, the more weights you have. But the purpose of convolutional layers is mostly to detect patterns. You should decide the kernel size based on the size of the patterns. A kernel size of 1 is nothing more than joining channels together, but without looking for lengthy patterns. It's almost the same as using a dense layer in 3D data. Often the best size is 3, and you stack a series of convolutions and maxpoolings to detect larger patterns. In convolutoinal layers, the "filters" are compared to neurons.

Comment: `print(layer.kernel.shape)` will also print number of channels in each of the filters and how many filters are being used. For example, in the format of  `(filter_height, filter_width, the_number_of_channels_in_each_of_that_layer's_filters_IN_OTHER_WORDS_the_number_of_channels_in_that_layer's_input, the_number_of_filters_are_being_used_in_that_layer)`